# Monitor the rate of log file writes matching a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, logging, monitoring

I have a timestamped log file that I am watching.   Every so often the log writes a message, "OK"

How could I capture the number of "OK"s written per second?    E.g. output like

```
10.5 OK/sec
9 OK/sec
20 OK/sec
```

The log is pretty big,  its not practical to do a grep on the entire file.   I started with

```
tail -f my.log | grep OK
```

which is helpful but doesn't quite get me the rate.

Thanks!

First solution below is great (and other is good too),  I altered it a bit and this is what I came up with

```
tail -f my.log | perl -lne 'if(/(\d+:\d+:\d+).*OK/) { print $1; }'| uniq -c
```

Comment: Due to buffering, counting the number of OKs written in a second can be very misleading. Doesn't the file have timestamps?

Comment: it has timestamps, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your log is in form like:

```
Wed Jul 10 22:44:00 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:00 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:00 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:00 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK
```

so, in form `timestamp OK`, you can try the simple:

```
tail -f logfile | uniq -c
```

and you will get the next result:

```
4 Wed Jul 10 22:44:00 CEST 2013 OK
8 Wed Jul 10 22:44:01 CEST 2013 OK 
^
+---- number of OK in the same timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick script to do it:

```
#! /bin/bash
log="/var/log/messages"
seconds="1"
filter="OK"

while true; do
    echo "$(timeout $seconds tail -n0 -f $log|grep $filter|wc -l) OK/sec" 
done
```

There's a bit of a race condition where it might lose one or two lines during the loop, but it is unlikely.  Also, not every Linux distro has `timeout` installed by default, so you might want to check.